# Parallel export of *.mat to *.csv in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

In Matlab R2013b, I'm trying to export contents of *.mat files to *.csv in parallel. The generated csv files are large (around 60MB) and take 15 minutes to produce. So I tried to run them in parallel on a 32-core machine.

Here's my code:

```
% preFilter.m
globalStart = tic;
files = rdir('**\*.mat'); % list directory and subdirectories recursively

parfor i = 1:length(files)
    localStart = tic;
    file = files(i,1).name;
    stats = strcat('[ ',num2str(i),' / ', num2str(length(files)),' ]');
    disp(strcat(stats,' File : ',file));

    doWork(file, strcat(file,'.csv'));

    fprintf(strcat('Current trace time: ',num2str(toc(localStart)), ' s.\n\n'))

end

fprintf(strcat('\nAll traces time: ',num2str(toc(globalStart)), ' s.\n'))
```

And the actual worker:

```
% doWork.m
function doWork(inFile, outFile)
    contents = load(inFile);
    temp_table = struct2table(contents.mess);
    filteredTable= temp_table(:, {'x','y'}); % filter only x and y columns
    writetable(filteredTable, outFile);
end
```

This code makes use of [rdir](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19550-recursive-directory-listing/content/rdir.m) for recursive listing of current- and subdirecories containing *.mat files, but unfortunately runs in serial, although I've specified the for as a parfor.

What could be the problem, I would expect the the doWork() functions to run in parallel here.. ?

Comment: 60MB does not sound that large... Do you know, what is the bottleneck? Which line is responsible for this running time?

Comment: writetable(filteredTable, outFile) is where the bottleneck occurs, where the actual output file is produced. I don't understand why it blocks and doesn't get delegated to a separate thread...

Comment: Does a parallel pool open when you hit `parfor`? If not, you need to open one manually using `parpool`.

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'parpool'.
Could it be that I'm actually missing the Parallel Toolbox? But why would parfor be accepted as a valid command then?!